# docker-compose build contains unsupported option: 'network'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make docker-compose run through system proxy, and according to [docker compose file doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network)

network option could be added in compose file like this:

```
build:
  context: .
  network: host
```

And my compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  flasky:
    build:
      context: "."
      network: host
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy 
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    links:
      - mysql:dbserver
      - elasticsearch:elasticsearch
  mysql:
    image: "mysql/mysql-server:5.7"
    env_file: .env-mysql
    restart: always
  elasticsearch:
    image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0"
    env_file: .env-es
    restart: always
```

When trying to run "docker-compose up", I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.flasky.build contains unsupported option: 'network'
```

I think i did exactly as the example in doc, no ideas what is wrong here.
Any help?

Comment: This option was added in compose version `3.4` and you are using version `3`.

Comment: @michalk this said, is not as obvious when you start with `docker-compose` and contradicts a little bit what is common in images, where image maintainer tend to make `my-image:3` being equal to `my-image:3.99` and not `my-image:3.0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your documentation article:

> Added in [version 3.4](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-34) file format

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network*</sup>

But you are on version `3.0`

See:

> **Note**: When specifying the Compose file version to use, make sure to
> specify both the *major* and *minor* numbers. If no minor version is
> given, `0` is used by default and not the latest minor version. As a
> result, features added in later versions will not be supported. For
> example:
>
> ```yaml
> version: "3"
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```yaml
> version: "3.0"
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3*</sup>

So your fix would just be to change your `version` from `version: 3` to, at least, `version: 3.4`

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
  flasky:
    build:
      context: "."
      network: host
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy 
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    links:
      - mysql:dbserver
      - elasticsearch:elasticsearch
  mysql:
    image: "mysql/mysql-server:5.7"
    env_file: .env-mysql
    restart: always
  elasticsearch:
    image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0"
    env_file: .env-es
    restart: always
```

Comment: Thank you so much! after specifying minor version number everything works fine:)